# How do detect when someone makes a call from an Android device in an AIR application?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I want to be able to read the contact number of the person to whom the call was made and read when the call ends. I have been googling but couldn't really find anything. How can I achieve this? any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to write an Air native extension (ANE) for Android that creates a class that inherits BroadcastReceiver, you could than wrap actions such as ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL as ActionScript events to broadcast the phone number, contact info, etc.. to your event handlers.

[Developing and using Adobe AIR native extensions for Android device](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/ane-android-devices.html)

*Example Android java:*

```
public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String extraState = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
            Log.d("test", "ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL");
        }
        else {
            Log.d("test", "ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED");
            if (extraState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                Log.d("test", "EXTRA_STATE_RINGING");
            } 
            else if (extraState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                Log.d("test", "EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK");
            }
            else if (extraState.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                Log.d("test", "EXTRA_STATE_IDLE");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really good in java.. i guess I have to start learning.  Thanks for the answer. appreciate it!